# Looking for Locations API (c#)

Tags: c#, location

In my app i am allowing users to enter there current city, for that i need an organised list of countries, states and cities on my server.

I am looking for an api that's available on net through which i get can download orgainsed list of countries, states and cities and store it on my server in format of my choice in db.

**Edit 1**

I am **not** looking for functionality of how to do or implement this,  Iam  actually looking for a place (website) from where i can download countries  list respective states and cities in .zip/.rar format **or**  make web-requests to an url and that url returns me list of countries/states/cities in any format (i will handle the format) , that i can process and store on my server in Database.

Answer (score 3):

[Have a look at this API.](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csharp) May be helpful and it's free.

Comment: http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/worldcities/


The direct link if you just want do download all the records

Answer (score 2):

The United Nations [maintain a list of locations](http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/service/main.htm) around the world which is fairly comprehensive. you could also look at using data from OpenStreetMap, although you *may* find the data quality varies regionally.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at SimpleGeo as well, https://simplegeo.com/tools/